# codeigniter get int value from string

Tags: codeigniter, integer

I have a table with int values there. But, when I try to get the query result they all become strings in array.

Controller

```
$hitung['total'] = $this->nilais->ambil_total($id)->result();
```

var_dump result

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#21 (1) { ["bobot"]=> string(2) "20" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#22 (1) { ["bobot"]=> string(2) "30" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#23 (1) { ["bobot"]=> string(2) "30" } }
```

I want to add each integer `(20 + 30 + 30)`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply covert the string to int or u can use array_sum() to add

Answer (score 0):

intval — Get the integer value of a variable

Returns the integer value of var, using the specified base for the conversion (the default is base 10). intval() should not be used on objects, as doing so will emit an E_NOTICE level error and return 1.

```
<?php
echo intval(42);                      // 42
echo intval(4.2);                     // 4
echo intval('42');                    // 42
echo intval('+42');                   // 42
echo intval('-42');                   // -42
echo intval(042);                     // 34
echo intval('042');                   // 42
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first store value in variable from object like

```
$a=your_object_variable[0]->bobot;
$b=your_object_variable[1]->bobot;
$c=your_object_variable[2]->bobot;
$sum=(int)$a+(int)$b+(int)$c;
echo $sum
```